# Laravel 5:Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php

```
<?php $results = DB::select('select * from insurance_policy where Id = ?', [1]);

                                           $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
                                            echo $row["Amount"];
                                  ?>
```

Here is my code it is giving me a error:Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. 
I am using Laravel 5

Comment: how should i fix the error

Answer (score 0):

`DB::select` would return an `Array` which stores the DB rows.
You can iterate the results

```
foreach ($results as $row) { echo $row['Amount']; }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying now this error comes. #Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

Comment: It seems that the previous answer is not correct. I changed it. :)

Comment: Hi sorry for being a pain no w have got this error:#Cannot use object of type stdClass as array